# Is there a way to make a rectangular frame auto resize in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

I realize it's a bit of a strange question, but I didn't want to make the title too long. In InDesign CC, you can edit a text box so that it auto resizes based on the amount of text contained within it.

Is there a way to do something similar in Photoshop? If you want to make a variety of buttons for a brand, they of course have to be consistent, so it would be nice if there was a way to set a text frame with the style, color, and amount of padding you want so that whenever you type in your text you don't have to sit there making sure it's consistent with the rest.

I want to be able to make a file like this, then save it in the CC library so that it can be dragged out and used as a template of sorts-- or have we not gotten that far with Photoshop yet?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Short answer: no.  Maybe there is some scripting that can do this, but I have no clue.